# C# Compare a string to a SqlExtension

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am currently working with SQL on my C# asp.net page.
I insert a value into the Database, but then if the ID is duplicate I get this exception:

> {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Section'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Section'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

What I want to do is to treat the exception doing something like:

```
  if(exception=={"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Section'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Section'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."})
  //update values instead of insert
```

My problem is that I can't compare exception(which is a string) with that long "string" that I get from trying to duplicate the IDs.

Is there anyway that I can compare this so that I can properly work on a solution to this error?

Comment: detect the conflict before you try inserting. That's what we should do.

Comment: try using exception.tostring().equals("Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Section'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Section'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.")

Comment: @KingKing Your solution is fundamentally flawed in any system with more than one user.

Comment: @podiluska what about `transaction`? My comment is just against the OP's request, he wants to detect if there is any conflict, but he doesn't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should catch the `SqlException` (which will probably be the InnerException of your exception) and check its `Number` property to identify the exception.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I would use a try catch block to check for a SqlException. Something like this:

```
 private bool SaveDocument()
 {
        bool saved = false;
        try
        {
            Save();
            saved = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           string errorTitle = Resources.SaveErrorCaption;
           string errorText = Resources.SaveErrorText;
           Exception initialEx = ex;
            while (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                if (ex.InnerException is SqlException)
                {
                    int errorNo = ((SqlException)ex.InnerException).Number;

                    if (errorNo == 2627)
                    {
                        errorTitle = Resources.DuplicateEntryErrorTitle;
                        errorText = Resources.DuplicateEntryErrorMessage;
                    }
                }
                ex = ex.InnerException;
            }
            MsgBox.Show(errorTitle, errorText,
                string.Format("{0}{1}StackTrace:{1}{2}", initialEx.Message, Environment.NewLine, initialEx.StackTrace),
                MsgBoxButtons.OK, MsgBoxImage.Error);
        }
         return saved;
}
```

Comment: `saved=false;` in the catch block is redundant.